# Magento: assign all product to Default Category

Tags: php, mysql, magento

How can I assign all my product to default category?

I would not loose the actual category assigned but I would add also default category.

On this way PRODUCT A that has Category 1 will have also Default Category and PRODUCT B that have any category assigned will have only Dafault category.

Thanks

Comment: You have to get product collection and set category_id in every product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using this custom script:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$default_category_id = [your default category id];
$db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT product_id FROM catalog_category_product WHERE category_id != ?";
$pIds = $db->fetchAll($sql, array($default_category_id));
foreach($pIds as $pid) {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO catalog_category_product (category_id, product_id, position) VALUES (?,?,1)";
   $db->query($sql, array($default_category_id, $pid));
}
?>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I have an error:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''app/Mage.php'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home2/tamracit/public_html/script_cat.php on line 2

Comment: require_once 'app/Mage.php'; Please remove $ in this line #line2

Comment: on line 2 there are not $ char. Where I should remove it?

Comment: I have a new error:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getConnection() on a non-object in /home2/tamracit/public_html/script_cat.php on line 5

Comment: Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

Comment: I don't understand...you code seeems to be the same from first version. Can you check?

Comment: Now I have this error:


15-Dec-2014 08:37:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tamracit_12mar2014`.`amracing__catalog_category_product`, CONSTRAINT `FK_OZSS_CAT_CTGR_PRD_CTGR_ID_OZSS_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `amracing__catalog_catego)' in /home2/tamracit/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Comment: Oops. You can't use the category id which was not created. Please check your category id if it exists in catalog_category_entity

Comment: Categoty exists: I would add DEFAULLT CATEGORY that has ID "2"

Answer (score 1):

I always try to avoid running direct SQL queries when you can use the existing models. This is how I would do it:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addStoreFilter($store_id) // Or use the default Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::DEFAULT_STORE_ID 
->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
// You may need to specify a limit if you have too many products with: ->setPageSize(NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS)

$newCategories = array(12345); // Put as much categories as you want to add

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    // array_merge: To keep the existing ids
    // array_unique: to avoid assigning the same category twice
    $product->setCategoryIds(
    array_unique(array_merge($product->getCategoryIds(), $newCategories))
    );
    $product->save();
}
```

You will probably need to reindex afterwards (if you have disabled update on save in your reindex settings) in order to the changes to take effect.

Comment: $newCategories = array(12345); 
I should replace "12345" with my DEFAULT CATEGORY ID?

Comment: Yes, exactly, don't forget to backup your database first, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: I have this error:
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction' in /home2/tamracit/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228